# What's the equivalent of origin() in the latest kaboom?

Tags: javascript, game-development, kaboom

I think I'm following an outdated tutorial where using the `origin()` function to modify the anchor position of an object. But it seems like the function has been removed in the latest version.

```js
const player = add([
  rect(24, 24),
  pos(12, 12),
  color(0, 0, 1),
  area(),
  body(),
  origin("center"), //<--- undefined
]);
```

So How do I do it now in the latest kaboom version ?

Answer (score 1):

It's me from the future, I found it from documentation that we can use `anchor()` to do the same thing like the `origin()` function does.

Eg: `anchor("center")`

```js
add([
    text("Hello Kaboom", {
        align:"center",
    }),
    pos(k.width() * 0.5, k.height() * 0.5),
    anchor("center")

]);
```